# MVC Angular Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am working on a job posting website. i have been able to retrieve the jobs listing from the database and insert them in a table using angular repeat. I have each job displaying on the table with the properties:  jobId, jobTitle, jobDescription, dateAdded, dateStarted. I would like to be able to click on the jobId for a specific job and redirect to another view that will display all of that one specific job details. I have tried different ways but i am completely lost

CONTROLLER

'use strict';
    app.controller('searchResultCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Job) {

```
//retrieve jobs from sql database

$scope.jobArray = Job.query();
$scope.job = {
    jobId: '',
    jobTitle: '',
    description: '',
    startDate: '',
    dateCreated: ''
};

$scope.maxSize = 5;  //pagination settings
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.totalItems = 0;

$scope.jobId = '';



//retrieve job from job table and reroute to different view
  //I NEED HELP HERE

 $scope.getJob = function () {
   $scope.jobArray2 = Job.query({ id: 0 }, function () {
        $scope.job = {
            jobId: '',
            jobTitle: '',
            description: '',
            startDate: '',
            dateCreated: ''
        };
        $scope.jobTitle = '';
    });
    $location.path('/job'); //new html view to display individual job details
}

});
```

JOB LISTING VIEW

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in jobArray.slice(((currentPage-1)*maxSize), ((currentPage)*maxSize))      track by $index">
                        <td><a ng-click='getJob()'>{{job.jobId}}</a></td>
                        <td>{{job.jobTitle}}</td>
                        <td>{{job.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{job.startDate}}</td>
                        <td>{{job.dateCreated}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

NEW INDIVDUAL JOB VIEW

```
<h1>
                Title
            </h1>
            <h2>
             {{jobArray2[0].jobTitle}}
            </h2>
            <h3>Job Descrption:</h3>
            {{jobArray2[0].description}}
            <h3>Job Start Date</h3>
            {{jobArray2[0].startDate}}
            <h3>Date Created</h3>
            {{jobArray2[0].dateCreated}}
            <h3>Job Id</h3>
            {{jobArray2[0].jobId}}
            <h3>Responsibilities:</h3>
            <ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `job` into `getJob()` and set `$scope.job`...

```
$scope.getJob = function (job) {
    $scope.job = job;
    $location.path('/job'); // I'm assuming this part works and switches to your details view
}
```

Then pass the job in on ngClick...

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in jobArray.slice(((currentPage-1)*maxSize), ((currentPage)*maxSize))      track by $index">
    <td><a ng-click='getJob(job)'>{{job.jobId}}</a></td>
    <td>{{job.jobTitle}}</td>
    <td>{{job.description}}</td>
    <td>{{job.startDate}}</td>
    <td>{{job.dateCreated}}</td>

</tr>
```

Your details view can reference $scope.job...

```
<h1>
    Title
</h1>
<h2>
 {{job.jobTitle}}
</h2>
<h3>Job Descrption:</h3>
{{job.description}}
<h3>Job Start Date</h3>
{{job.startDate}}
<h3>Date Created</h3>
{{job.dateCreated}}
<h3>Job Id</h3>
{{job.jobId}}
<h3>Responsibilities:</h3>
<ul>
```

Comment: i did exactly as you posted, nothing is happening. there are no errors in the console either? what else do you think it could be?